# Shell-script to execute object to another instance

Tags: shell, unix, plsql

I want to move my entire PL/SQL object.. packages/alter scripts/create scripts etc.
to another instance.

For this is there a unix script ?
Can anyone guide with the steps to be followed. I dont know unix.

Comment: Sounds like a question for Server Fault.

Comment: @alamar - server fault ? 
Is teh question not valid.

Comment: Sounds like a job for exp/imp or expdp/impdp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move DB-objects i would use datapump with a db-link.

You can find more infos on this site:

[Oracle direct export to remote database tips](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_direct_export_remote_database.htm)